# Cast number of bytes from blob field to number

Tags: mysql

I have a table with one blob field named bindata. bindata always contains 7 bytes. First four of them is an integer (unsigned I think, db is not mine).

My question is how can I select only the first four bytes from bindata and convert them to a number?

I am new in mySQL but from the documentation I see that I may have to use the conv function by doing something like this:

```
SELECT CONV(<Hex String of first 4 bytes of bindata>,16,10) as myNumber
```

But I don't have a clue on how to select only the first four bytes of the blob field. I am really stuck here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string function to get partial of byte in the blob. For example:

```
SELECT id, 
       ((ORD(SUBSTR(`data`, 1, 1)) << 24) +
        (ORD(SUBSTR(`data`, 2, 1)) << 16) +
        (ORD(SUBSTR(`data`, 3, 1)) << 8) +
         ORD(SUBSTR(`data`, 4, 1))) AS num
FROM test;
```

Here is [Demo in SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c732/17)